# How the h c t l numbers read from in lsscsi?

Tags: scsi

When doing lsscsi:

```
$lsscsi

[0:0:2:0] disk FUJITSU MAM3184MP 0105 /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0] cd   CREATIVE CD5233E 1.00 /dev/scd0
```

In my understanding:

H : SCSI host id

C : SCSI channel

T : Target Number

L : LUN

How do the 4 numbers from? Does it read from BIOS? or they were decided by OS?

any other Linux command can get these numbers too?

Comment: The kernel detects SCSI interfaces and numbers them. H is that number. An interface can have several channels. If it does, the information comes from the interface. The target is the address on the bus, coming from the storage device. The LUN also comes from the storage device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are assigned by the kernel (and its device drivers), based on hardware information where appropriate. Thus on a real parallel SCSI setup, the second field will identify the bus on the corresponding HBA, the third field will identify the target (which is commonly determined by jumpers on each device), and the fourth identifies a subset of the target (which is determined by the target).

All this is exposed under `/sys/block` on Linux, so any command can look there for the relevant information. `lsscsi` does have its own nomenclature in some cases, *e.g.* for NVMe devices (with “N” in the host field), but all the information used is also available under `/sys/block`.

Comment: Can I say, H is decided by the kernel ( so it may change after reboot ). The C T L were decided by device, so it should be constant?

Comment: Yes, that’s accurate; H can change (except for NVMe devices), the rest are fixed and won’t change without a change in hardware.

Comment: Why NVMe device will not change?

Comment: Because their host is always identified as `N`.